# Pattern Design for commands

Tags: java, design-patterns, command

I want to create a a java program which will recive some commands. I'd like create a GUI for this program in the future, but now I want to use the programm using commands. I think that I do not need run a console to send commands, I should be for example, if my program is called managedProgram and shutdown is a command for this program a called example will be:

shutdown -hours to shutdown the machine at -hours.
 or 
shutdown -minutes to shutdown the machine in -minutes minutes.

I have created a a class for each command which may have a method to execute the command whit differents input parameters. A main class which recives the arguments ( the command and the parameters of the command) and call the class needed to execute the input command. However this structure is error prone, because I have a lot of conditional sequences (if, elseif else.. or swith) so I think that If I use a correct pattern design to change the hierarchy I will have a extensible and reusable estructure. For example, I'd like create a GUI when the program is ended.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

> A behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to represent
>   and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later
>   time. This information includes the method name, the object that owns
>   the method and values for the method parameters.

If you implement this pattern it will be easy for you to reuse it from GUI, since GUI actions will be mapped to proper commands.